# Sharing data between components by service gets read only in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I'm sharing data by shared service between three components.
Data object in component gets read only and can't be changed neither by form input, nor inside component manually.
After subscribing data inside component, objec

```html
  ngOnInit() {
    this.paramsService.currentParams.subscribe(params => this.params = params);
  }
```

it's compiled without errors, but on input change, this.params object stay unchanged.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Do you mean if another component changes it, then the value is not updated across all components?

Comment: You most likely subscribe before any value is pushed into `this.paramsService.currentParams`. You might want to use `ReplaySubject(1)` or `BehaviorSubject` instead

Comment: Can you please share more details or a dummy code snippet which can explain what exactly you are trying to do. It will give more insights while answering

Answer (score 0):

In paramsService

```
var currentParams= new BehaviourSubject("initial value")
```

you can change the value by

```
currentParams.next("new value")
```

any time when you subscribe to currentParams, you always will have the latest value

Comment: the problem is, that, the compontent should get params from inputs, but as the params object (which is subscribed to the service) is read only, input changes do not affect the object

Comment: need to see your template code in order to find out what you want to achieve